# One user account for many computers

Tags: active-directory

Now ( in workgroup ) we have almost 20 computers on which we use the same ( generic) name for user account. This computers are used by many users which are changing very often.All of them are using only one application.

In Active Directory will be OK to make only one account which to be used simultaneous on this computers?

Thank you!

Comment: do already have experience with AD, from the sounds of it you don't so I'd think this would be a great deal of work for a novice to setup AD and I don't think you'd gain anything in this case.

Comment: @tony roth: I don't have to much experience but we have to implement AD. The management of user account and computers ( almost 100 beside this 20) has became verry dificult in workgroup.

Comment: sounds like you are at reasonable place to start using AD and I'd recommend it but you don't need AD to easily accomplish the above listed requirements. But if this is just the tip of the iceberg in terms of requirements then yes AD is the way, otherwise some very simple scripts could do the job also.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the same practices can be duplicated with an AD account - along with all the same challenges when it comes to managing accountability.